# What is the opposite of a loanword?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, linguistics, affixes

- The words in a language that weren't borrowed.

Comment: These two things have nothing to do with one another, are you asking two separate questions?

Comment: Yes, so I wouldn't have to wait a few minutes to post another question.

Comment: Please make them into two questions (you should be able to make another one now) because it's hard to answer a question completely when you have two questions in a post. thanks!

Comment: "Opposite" is not a term that applies to everything; language and words are multi-dimensional and don't always have binary oppositions.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably looking for **native word**.

From Linda Correli's article ["Brief Etymological Review of the English Word-Stock"](http://www.omniglot.com/language/articles/etymology.htm):

> Etymologically the vocabulary of the English language is far from being homogenous. It consists of two layers - the native stock of words and the borrowed stock of words. Numerically the borrowed stock of words is considerably larger than the native stock of words.
>
> In fact native words comprise only 30% of the total number of words in the English vocabulary but the native words form the bulk of the most frequent words actually used in speech and writing. Besides, the native words have a wider range of lexical and grammatical valency, they are highly polysemantic and productive in forming word clusters and set expressions.
>
> Borrowed words or loanwords are words taken from another language and modified according to the patterns of the receiving language.